# creating pointer arrays in c++ with help of new keyword

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

What's the meaning of the code below?

```
int **matrix = new int*[n]
```

What's the difference here between `matrix` and `int*[n]`?

Comment: I would suggest grabbing a beginner’s C++ book or a tutorial to learn the basic syntax of C++. The question about difference doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: Thnkq for the suggestion.I'm new to stack overflow, I'll take care from next time.Thnks

Comment: thanks for the question . it clarified my doubt .

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have declared a double pointer(of type int) called matrix and allocated an array of n int* pointers.
 Now you can use matrix[i] as an int* pointer (0 <= i < n).
 Later you might want to allocate memory to individual pointers as well like matrix[i] = new int[size];(size is an int or more appropriately size_t)

Answer (score 1):

for instance there is cricket team and you need

Since you have Cricket* team;, this indicates you have one of two possible

situations:

1) a pointer to a single CricketPlayer (or any derived) type

2) a pointer to an array of CricketPlayer (but not derived) types.

What you want is a pointer to an array of CricketPlayer or derived types. So you

need the **.

You'll also need to allocate each team member individually and assign them to the array:

```
            // 5 players on this team

          CricketPlayer** team = new CricketPlayer*[5];

          // first one is a bowler

          team[0] = new Bowler();

         // second one is a hitter

          team[1] = new Hitter();

           // etc
```

// then to deallocate memory

```
         delete team[0];
         delete team[1];
         delete[] team;
```

In your query,

```
           It can be understood as

              int *matrix[]=new int*[n];
```

SO there are n  pointers pointing to n places.

Because

```
               int *foo;

                foo=new int[5];
```

will also create 5 consecutive places but it is the same pointer.

[image: see this]

In our case it is array of pointers

Answer (score 1):

It is an array of 'n' pointers, for which memory can be allocated and initialized in loop.
If n is 3, it is an array of 3 elements and each is pointer to int, can point to set of array of integer values like below.

```
            matrix[0] -> Ox001  points to  array of int [ 1 2 3 4]
            matrix[1] -> Ox017                          [ 5 6 7 8]
            matrix[2] -> Ox024                          [ 9 10 11 12]
```

Sample code like this

```
           int **m = new int*[3];
           for(auto i=0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               m[i] = new int[3];
               for(auto j=0; j < 3; j++)
                   m[i][j] = 0;
           }


           for(auto i=0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               m[i] = new int[3];
               for(auto j=0; j < 3; j++)
                   cout << m[i][j];
               cout << "\n";
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to notice some thing as follows:

- `int *p` means that `p` is a pointer that points to an `int` variable or points to an array of int variables.
- `int* *p` means that `p` is a pointer that points to an `int*` variable or points to an array of `int*` variables.
- `new int[5]` is an array of 5 `int` variables.
- `new int*[5]` is an array of 5 `int*` variables.

In this case, `matrix` is the second type so it can point to an array of `int*` variables so the statement:`int **matrix = new int*[n]`  is legal

Answer (score 0):

`matrix` is an **object** of type `int **`. This type is a pointer to pointer to `int`.

On the other hand, `int *` is a **type**, a pointer to `int`.

The **expression**:

```
new int*[n]
```

creates `n` adjacent objects of type `int *` somewhere in memory and returns a pointer to the first of them. In other words, it allocates and constructs `n` pointers to `int`; and returns a pointer to the first. Since the first (and each of them) are `int *`, the pointer *pointing to the first* is, in turn, of type `int **`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be absolutely clear if you remember the operator associativity and precedence.

Going by that int *[n] will be interpreted by compiler : as array of " n pointer to integers".(as [ ] has greater precedence than *, so for easy understanding, compiler interprets it that way.).

Now comming to other side int ** matrix is pointer to pointer.
When you created an array of pointer,you basically have the address of the first location ,here first location stores an pointer to integer.

So,when you are storing the address of the first address of such array you will need pointer to a pointer to point the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

//code for passing matrix as pointer and returning as a pointer

```
 int ** update(int ** mat)
{
    mat[0][1]=3;


    return mat;
}


int main()
{   int k=4;
    int **mat = new int*[k];

           for(auto i=0; i < k; i++)
           {
               mat[i] = new int[k];
               for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
               {
                   if(i==j)
                     mat[i][j]=1;
                   else
                    mat[i][j]=0;
               }

           }

          mat=update(mat);
           for(auto i=0; i < k; i++)
           {

               for(auto j=0; j < k; j++)
                   cout << mat[i][j];
               cout << "\n";
           }
    return 0;
}
```